# tr:nth-child(even) help. how to apply to one class?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-tables

I'm not very good with CSS and I need some help.

I have a table where i want every other row to be gray and the alternating rows to be white. but i only want it to happen on one particular table.

I added some code to my CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {  
background: #CCC;  
}  

tr:nth-child(odd) {  
background: #FFF;  
}
```

but the problem is that its affecting every table on my site.
I haven't found any examples where it applies only to a certain class. Is that possible? I want it to apply only to:

```
table.dashboardtable
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the CSS descendant combinator (juxtaposition) as usual:

```
table.dashboardtable tr:nth-child(even)
table.dashboardtable tr:nth-child(odd)
```

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what i needed. for some reason i was putting a dot between dashboardtable and tr. what a dumb mistake. lol.

Comment: I imagine that it might be a good idea to use `table.dashboardtable > tr:nth-child` (the child selector `>`), so that if you have nested tables it doesn't accidentally apply to those.

Answer (score 2):

`nth-child` and `nth-of-type` accept `odd` and `even` as well as a formula like `an+b`, where `a` and `b` are constants.

Usually you want to use `nth-of-type`, which will only apply to the type you specify. That will leave out other elements. If you want every even tr to have that background color, then try:

```
tr:nth-of-type(2n){
  background: #CCC;
}

tr:nth-of-type(2n+1){
  background: #FFF;
}
```

[More info on CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/)

Comment: ive only tried with ff3, but odd and even are working for me. ill switch to the formula just in case there are browsers that dont support the words though. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this makes sense of it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #customers tr:nth-child(even){
        background-color:white;
      }
      #customers tr:nth-child(odd){
        background-color:Lavender;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>In your markup define your table:</p>
      <table id="customers"></table>
  </body>
</html>
```